# Azure ARM Portal - Server 2016 VM - Configure NSGs for NETMQ on a specific TCP port

Tags: azure, tcp, azure-virtual-network, azureportal, network-security-groups

My NetMq server application is listening on port 5556 and I have the following inbound rules defined in the Azure portal...

[image]

[image]

Outbound rules are...

[image]

The client is coming in over the internet.

I have temporarily switch off the firewalls on the test VM whilst I try and get the Azure configuration correct.

Does the inbound rule look correct?

On the outbound side; what should the source tag be set to? The screenshot shows the source tag set to "Internet" but I have tried it with the source set to Any and it still doesn't work.

Thx!

Comment: I think we should check your NETMQ which port listen on. Please run this command to check it: netstat -ant | findstr 5556

Comment: @Jason - got "TCP    127.0.0.1:5556         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost" from that command which looks like it's listening on the expected port.

Comment: can you telnet this port from the outside?

Comment: @Jason No I can not connect via telnet.

Comment: @Jason NSG is Source : Any/TCP/5556 with Destination : Any/5556

Comment: Just want to open port  TCP 5556?

Comment: Yes, I have a NetMq server application listening on Port 5556 which should receive "requests" from a client over the Internet and return a "response" over the Internet to the client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147145/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-inthegarden).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, your app listen on `127.0.0.1:5556`, we should change it to `0.0.0.0:5556`